# Bit data type in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my table `student`,there is only one column attendence of `bit(1)` data type.
But when I am inserting 1 or 0.

```
Insert into student values(B'1');
```

Then it give output as some character like `'?'`..
why so??

Comment: [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html) may help

Comment: Check ASCII table about what `0x0` and `0x1` bits represent

Comment: why don't use a boolean type? or a int(1)?